# Criteria Query using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Using :-
    Postgres : PostgreSQL 10.0
    Hibernate      : 4.0.1

I have the following example table created in Postgres

```
CREATE TABLE Automobile
(id                          SERIAL               
,name                        VARCHAR(20)        
,year                        INTEGER        
);
```

I have created a domain Automobile class.

I have the following hibernate criteria query to return all the names for a particular year.

```
    final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria (Automobile.class);

    criteria.add (Restrictions.eq ("year", 1 ));

    List<Automobile> list = criteria.list();
```

However, the list() is generating the following exception.

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

So I changed query to pass in a String value for the "year" :-

```
    criteria.add (Restrictions.eq ("year", new String("1")));

    List<Automobile> list = criteria.list();
```

However, the list() is generating a different exception.

```
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
    Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Position: 1145
```

Any thoughts on what maybe the cause and solution that would return me list of matches please ?

Thank you 
Pete.

Comment: Show us your entity.

Comment: public class Automobile 
    {
     private String name;
     private String year;
// getter and setter methods
}
Hibernate Mappings
 <hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="my.domain.Automobile" table="AUTOMOBILE">
   <id name="id" column="AUTOMOBILE_ID">
    <generator class="sequence">
     <param name="sequence">automobile_seq</param>
    </generator>
   </id>
   <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="NAME" />
   </property>
   <property name="year" type="java.lang.String" >
    <column name="YEAR" />
   </property>
  </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>

Comment: sorry the formatting is not great
but I just realized that I have defined  "year" as a String in Dao,Domain and Hibernate mapping  but the database table it is a defined as Integer. 
Will change and re try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Hibernate mapping you have

```
<property name="year" type="java.lang.String" >
```

You didn't show you Java code. I suppose **year** is also String there.

But in the database **year** is an integer.

Solution: Change your mapping as follows:
    
Also change your Java class and define **year** as Integer.

Comment: Thank you Mentallurg for a quick response.